# xypic and the "`\frm{.}`"

Tags: xy-pic

When I use xelatex engine to compile the following code ,

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{% main packages
    amsmath,
    mathtools,
    amsfonts,
    amssymb,
    amsthm,
    tcolorbox,
    xcolor
}
\usepackage[%
    all,%
    pdf % 
]{xy}

\begin{document}
\SelectTips{xy}{}
\xy
0*\cir<1.75pt>{};
*+<3pt>!!R(0)\hbox{\scalebox{5}{%
    \color{lightgray}Object%
}}*\frm{-}="obj"; 0;
"obj"!!R *\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!L \txt{\tt R }*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
"obj"!!L *\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!R \txt{\tt L }*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
"obj"!!U *\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!D \txt{\tt U }*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
"obj"!!D *\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!U \txt{\tt D }*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
"obj"!!DR*\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!UL\txt{\tt DR}*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
"obj"!!DL*\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!UR\txt{\tt DL}*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
"obj"!!UR*\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!DL\txt{\tt UR}*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
"obj"!!UL*\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!DR\txt{\tt UL}*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
"obj"!!CR*\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!DL\txt{\tt CR}*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
"obj"!!CL*\cir<1pt>{}*+<5pt>!DR\txt{\tt CL}*\frm{.} **\dir{.}*{\UseTips\dir{>}},
\endxy
\end{document}
```

I got a strange error

[image]

However there will be no error

- if I remove the xyoption "pdf" , but the results looks ugly if I want to color the boxes and circles
- if I replace all the `*\frm{.}` by `*\frm{-}` .

So how can I fix this problem ? thanks